# How do I optimize pyspark to use all cores across all nodes?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

So I was running a: 5 node cluster with 16cores each in Google DataProc

Let say that applying a simple function across 1000 rows finishes at 50secs.

```
rows = df.limit(1000).collect()
[func(row) for row in rows] # runs ~50secs
```

In my assumption, if I fully utilize all cores in the cluster, that would give me a runtime of roughly:

```
total_cores = n_nodes * (n_core_per_node - 1)
total_cores = 5 * 15 = 75

50secs / 75cores = 0.667secs runtime across 1000 rows
```

So I've partitioned the df by 75 so that each executor has 15 partitions in them. And since each executor has 15cores, each of these partition would get their own core:

```
conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.setAll([
    ('spark.executor.cores', '15'), 
    ('spark.executor.instances', '5')
])
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
df.limit(1000).repartition(75).foreachPartition(func) # runs ~7secs
```

But I wasn't able to get the result that I'm expecting (just a runtime of ~0.667 secs).

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) states the following:

> Spark properties mainly can be divided into two kinds: one is related
> to deploy, like `spark.driver.memory`, `spark.executor.instances`,
> this kind of properties may not be affected when setting
> programmatically through `SparkConf` in runtime, or the behavior is
> depending on which cluster manager and deploy mode you choose, so it
> would be suggested to set through configuration file or `spark-submit`
> command line options

Your code appears to be setting the configuration in runtime. Try setting it via the config file or command line, as they've suggested.